# PostgreSQL 9.0 implicit transactions not rolling back

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0 in production, and have started noticing that statement errors abort an implicit transaction that never gets rolled back. This same issue doesn't appear on my development box, which is at 9.2. I'm not sure if it's a bug, feature, or configuration parameter at this point.

Here's an example of the problem:

```
$ psql test
test=> SELECT foo;
ERROR:  column "foo" does not exist
LINE 1: select foo;
               ^
test=> SELECT VERSION()
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Of course, I don't have a transaction to begin with. I realize that PostgreSQL wraps all statements in an implicit single-statement transaction, but in my experience it's never needed to be rolled back when there's an error. I don't require an explicit rollback on my local development instance of PostgreSQL.

The only relevant information I've been able to find online indicated it's a result of `AUTOCOMMIT` being `off`, but it's set to `on` in both environments.

So what is this? A bug? A misconfiguration? How do I resolve it?

Comment: Interestingly, it works if I connect with the `psql` client from my development box. Is this possibly a buggy version of libpq?

Comment: Upgraded libpq and psql, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command in the psql client:

```
\echo :AUTOCOMMIT
```

If it says "off", then look for a .psqlrc file that contains either "\set AUTOCOMMIT off" or "\unset AUTOCOMMIT".